# Memory Histogram not showing on monitoring screen using JavaMelody 1.51

Tags: profiler, java-melody

The memory histogram is not showing up on monitoring screen. I am using websphere 7.0

I am not sure whether my ear is getting monitored or not.

Below is my monitoring.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <bean id="facadeMonitoringAdvisor" class="net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringAdvisor">
        <property name="pointcut">
            <bean class="org.springframework.aop.support.JdkRegexpMethodPointcut">
                <property name="pattern" value="com.x.y.*" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"/>

    <bean id="springDataSourceBeanPostProcessor" class="net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceBeanPostProcessor">

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Why do we need these last 2 beans??? and how to see memory histogram??

Comment: can anybody help me out here... ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between spring configuration and heap histogram to see the number of instances per class in memory: you were on a false track.

But you probably use IBM J9 with Websphere. And the heap histogram feature is not supported in javamelody when using IBM J9.